# iOS Homescreen Web App Not Showing Updates

Tags: ios, web, mobile-safari

For a school project I made a digital school menu. It is landmarkmenu.com . I made it as a web app by using `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` Also, I configured it for android so that people can book mark it on their Homescreens as well. One week has gone by now and I have gone to update the food items on the server however it does not show up on the bookmark version on the iPhone Homescreen. For instance, I corrected a capitalization error and nested `<p>` inside a `<li>` on it and it shows on a regular browser and not the bookmark version on an iPhone. Any ideas would be helpful because I am stumped.

Sorry if the question is confusing, I am a new user and am very desperate!

Comment: it is not updating. you have to open the page again in safari or delete it again, create a new bookmark. both are not good.

Answer (score 0):

They are cached version so try to change files like 'index.html' which are showed very first. Theoretically they are just short cuts to the webpage they should be updated in time.